# Is there an equivalent to fminimax in Python?

Tags: python, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

[fminimax](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fminimax.html) is a function in Matlab which solves minimax constraint problems.
Is there a function equivalent to fminimax in python?

Comment: Requests for resources are off-topic.

Comment: @jhpratt that's not a request for resource. asking for help to translate code from one language to another looks on spot to me

Comment: You can formulate this easily yourself: `min z` subject to `z >= fi(x)`

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen, we are talking about max min (or min max) problems. Or "minimizes the worst-case (largest) value of a set of multivariable functions, starting at an initial estimate". Does this formulation fits this case?

Comment: Obviously, that is the same. Let me render this in proper math in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following minimax problems are equivalent:

[image]

The second formulation is more well-behaved and can be solved with any NLP solver (that supports inequality constraints).